# Jquery dropdown control with tags

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know a good Jquery plugin control for dropdown list. A user should be able to select multiple values from dropdown list and those selected values should be displayed as tags in the same control.

Please see the attached image for reference.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to use 
http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/
or 
http://textextjs.com/

Both of them are very nice and easy to integrate into the project.